# In Winform, how to properly set DataGridViewCheckBoxCell ReadOnly flag and paint the square box as gray?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How to properly set the `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell.ReadOnly` property and paint it as gray? Original DataGridCheckBoxCell does not do that.

My `DataGridView` has its data from a `BindingSource`. Once the data is loaded, I then set specific cells to ReadOnly.

However, experiment shows it makes other cell's ReadOnly attribute as inconsistent. Numerous debug sessions show that -sometimes- other cells in the same column reinstantiates, thus resets its ReadOnly flag. This cause painting the cell to be inconsistent.

Below is the code for a working sample application. It has 4 rows. However, if you set a breakpoint on the cell's constructor, you will see it is instantiated more than 4 times. When you click the checkbox, sometimes you'll see the cell reinstantiates too. This really puzzles me.

I am running .NET 3.5

**Form1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DataGridPaintingIssue
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            estimateLineBindingSource.DataSource = createMockData();
            this.Load += Form_Load;
        }

        private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            setReadOnly();
        }

        private List<EstimateLineNet> createMockData()
        {
            var result = new List<EstimateLineNet>()
            {
                new EstimateLineNet("*", false, "HEADER"),
                new EstimateLineNet(null, false, "Child"),
                new EstimateLineNet(null, true, "openitem"),
                new EstimateLineNet(null, false, "Child3"),
            };
            return result;
        }

        private void setReadOnly()
        {
            estimateGridView.Rows[1].Cells[2].ReadOnly = true; //manually set a specific cell's ReadOnly flag.
        }
    }


    public class OpenItemCheckBoxColumn : DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    {
        public OpenItemCheckBoxColumn()
        {
            init();
        }
        private void init()
        {
            CellTemplate = new OpenItemCheckBoxCell();
        }

        public class OpenItemCheckBoxCell : DataGridViewCheckBoxCell
        {
            public OpenItemCheckBoxCell()
            {
                ;//breakpoint shows sometimes the cell reinstantiates.
            }

            private DataGridViewElementStates _lastState;
            private bool _lastReadOnly;

            protected override void Paint(
                Graphics graphics,
                Rectangle clipBounds,
                Rectangle cellBounds,
                int rowIndex,
                DataGridViewElementStates elementState,
                object value,
                object formattedValue,
                string errorText,
                DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
                DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
                DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
            {
                //breakpoint with condition _lastState != elementState shows the ReadOnly flag resets to false
                base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText,
                    cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
                _lastState = elementState;
                _lastReadOnly = ReadOnly; //need to persist this ReadOnly flag.
            }

        }
    }


    public class EstimateLineNet
    {
        public EstimateLineNet(string asterisk, bool openItem, string description)
        {
            Asterisk = asterisk;
            OpenItem = openItem;
            Description = description;
        }
        public string Asterisk { get; set; }
        public bool OpenItem { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Form1.Designer.cs**

```
namespace DataGridPaintingIssue
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.estimateGridView = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.Asterisk = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.OpenItem = new DataGridPaintingIssue.OpenItemCheckBoxColumn();
            this.Desc = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.estimateLineBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.estimateGridView)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.estimateLineBindingSource)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // estimateGridView
            // 
            this.estimateGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.estimateGridView.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.estimateGridView.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
            this.estimateGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            this.estimateGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight = 19;
            this.estimateGridView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;
            this.estimateGridView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.Asterisk,
            this.OpenItem,
            this.Desc});
            this.estimateGridView.DataSource = this.estimateLineBindingSource;
            this.estimateGridView.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.estimateGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.estimateGridView.Name = "estimateGridView";
            this.estimateGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.estimateGridView.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Asterisk
            // 
            this.Asterisk.DataPropertyName = "Asterisk";
            this.Asterisk.HeaderText = "*";
            this.Asterisk.MaxInputLength = 2;
            this.Asterisk.Name = "Asterisk";
            this.Asterisk.Width = 20;
            // 
            // OpenItem
            // 
            this.OpenItem.DataPropertyName = "OpenItem";
            this.OpenItem.HeaderText = "O";
            this.OpenItem.Name = "OpenItem";
            this.OpenItem.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
            this.OpenItem.SortMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
            this.OpenItem.Width = 30;
            // 
            // Desc
            // 
            this.Desc.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            this.Desc.DataPropertyName = "Description";
            this.Desc.HeaderText = "Description";
            this.Desc.MaxInputLength = 60;
            this.Desc.Name = "Desc";
            // 
            // estimateLineBindingSource
            // 
            this.estimateLineBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(DataGridPaintingIssue.EstimateLineNet);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
            this.Controls.Add(this.estimateGridView);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.estimateGridView)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.estimateLineBindingSource)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Asterisk;
        private OpenItemCheckBoxColumn OpenItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Desc;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView estimateGridView;
        private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource estimateLineBindingSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After approaching this issue from multiple sides for weeks, I found that every time the DataGrid bound data is refreshed, all its `CellTemplate` are reinstantiated. Thus, all of its previous ReadOnly values are lost. The answer is to set the ReadOnly values again after every refresh.

If you use Cell property (like ReadOnly) to do custom painting, like me, remember to set the value first and repaint the cell again, on every DataGrid data refresh.

DataGrid data refresh -> cell painted with defaults -> set custom cell properties -> repaint cell again

Comment: I [mentioned this Nov 16th](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703157/in-winform-how-to-properly-set-datagridviewcheckboxcell-readonly-flag-and-paint/33741151#comment55252910_33741151).

Comment: @OhBeWise Sorry, I didnt quite get that you mention it. You want to edit your posting ? I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: No no, I don't mind. It's too bad that we misunderstood each other, that could have saved you weeks. >.<

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. If you just want the `ReadOnly OpenItemCheckBoxCell` to be painted gray add the following as the first line in your `Paint` method:

   ```
   this.Style.BackColor = this.ReadOnly ? Color.Gray : Color.White;
   ```
2. But if you want *any* `ReadOnly` cell painted gray, add the following event handler in your `Form1` constructor:

   ```
   estimateGridView.CellFormatting += estimateGridView_CellFormatting;

   private void estimateGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
   {
     DataGridViewCell cell = estimateGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
     cell.Style.BackColor = cell.ReadOnly ? Color.Gray : Color.White;
   }
   ```

In following option 2, you'll notice that all cells are `ReadOnly`. Check your `Form1.Designer` and you'll see why. Remove the following lines:

```
this.estimateGridView.ReadOnly = true;
this.Asterisk.ReadOnly = true;
this.OpenItem.ReadOnly = true;
this.Desc.ReadOnly = true;
```

Now you'll notice that the cell you're manually setting as `ReadOnly` is not a `OpenItemCheckBoxCell`. Make the following change and your test is complete:

```
private void setReadOnly()
{
    estimateGridView.Rows[1].Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
}
```

*Side note*: If you follow option 2, you can completely remove the custom `CheckBoxColumn` and `CheckBoxCell` classes.

*Additional Note*: If you only want to paint the actual `CheckBox` background gray - not the entire cell background - you'll have to override the paint method of the `CheckBox`. It's more work, but you can start by checking this article on how to [Create custom UI appearance for WinForms CheckBox](http://devblog.antongochev.net/2008/07/08/create-custom-ui-appearance-for-winforms-checkbox-part-2/). In this case, you won't want option 2.

Comment: Thank you for noticing the ReadOnly flags. I have removed them. But they are still reinstantiated from time to time. This cause the gray painting to reset to white.

Comment: @JesonMartajaya The only way I could reproduce this behavior was to reset `estimateGridView.DataSource`. If you are ever doing this, you'll need to reset your manually set `ReadOnly` cells.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behavior following those steps.

Comment: once the form is loaded, try the following: 1. set breakpoint inside OpenItemCheckBoxCell constructor 2. click the "openitem" checkbox. You will see the OpenItemCheckBoxCell reinstantiates and ReadOnly value is reset to false.